# Php: fwrite not atomic "on some platforms". I.e. what platforms?

Tags: php

Php's docs for `fwrite` [say](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fwrite.php):

> If handle was fopen()ed in append mode, fwrite()s are atomic (unless the size of string exceeds the filesystem's block size, on some platforms, and as long as the file is on a local filesystem)

On which platforms `fwrite` isn't atomic, if the length of the `string` is longer than the FS' block size? Is this only platform related or also filesystem type related (e.g. FAT32 vs NTFS)?

I'm not gonna lie, I'm mainly interested in the case of `fwrite`ing on Linux and ext4 local filesystem, which I'm pretty sure isn't included in the `on some platforms` clause, but still I'm interested what this clause means in practice.

Comment: Your fine as it states `local filesystem`, I think its aimed at NFS, glusterfs etc

Comment: @LawrenceCherone: I think _and as long as_ means both conditions.